# Why would getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute) not return proper labels?

Tags: plugin-development

I have `getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)` setup in my plugin file.  I have attributes defined in `defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes()`.  However when the page loads `$attribute` returns `field:85` instead of one of the expected labels. Why might this occur?

Comment: I've been wondering about this, too. I believe it changed when the Customizable Element Indexes were introduced with 2.5, but [the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) don't mention it and still use the handle-based syntax in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little digging in the source, and here's what's going on:

When Craft builds an element index, it pulls all available element attributes from the [ElementIndexesService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/ElementIndexesService), where the method [`getAvailableTableAttributes`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/ElementIndexesService.php#L250) adds all custom fields to the available attributes, with keys `'field:'.$field->id`.

The ElementIndexesService class was [added in Craft 2.5.2750](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/commits/master/app/services/ElementIndexesService.php), when a lot of things changed related to element indexes (this is when the [Customizable Element Indexes](https://pixelandtonic.com/blog/craft-2.5-beta) feature was added).

Before 2.5, things worked differently – custom attributes weren't "pre-fetched" by Craft, but had to be added manually using the `modifyEntryTableAttributes` hook, where the `$attribute` variable passed to `getEntryTableAttributeHtml` would be a custom field handle, not the current `field:{fieldId}` value.

It's unfortunate that [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) for `getEntryTableAttributeHtml` appear to not having been updated since Craft 2.4, as its current example code won't actually work (for custom fields) since 2.5.

Either way, here's a workaround which should make things a little bit easier in customizing the HTML for custom field attributes:

```
public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{

    // If custom field, get field handle
    if (strncmp($attribute, 'field:', 6) === 0)
    {
        $fieldId = substr($attribute, 6);
        $field = craft()->fields->getFieldById($fieldId);
        $attribute = $field->handle;
    }

    // Get html by attribute (field handle)
    switch ($attribute)
    {
        case 'customFieldHandle' :
            return '<span>'.$entry->$attribute.'</span>';
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this working as documented in Craft CMS 2.6.2776?

Comment: @aran Nope – neither the docs nor the relevant source code appears to have changed with 2.6.2776.